# Write image (byte array) to hdfs

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, udf

I have a pig UDF function written in java which is creating a chart and I need to save the chart to HDFS.

Code from java UDF:

`byte[] bytes = BitmapEncoder.getBitmapBytes(chart, BitmapFormat.PNG);`

How can I save the image (byte array) to HDFS ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it:

`byte[] bytes = BitmapEncoder.getBitmapBytes(chart, BitmapFormat.PNG);`

```
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(config);
    String s = fs.getHomeDirectory()+"/chart.png";
    Path path = new Path(s);
    FSDataOutputStream out = fs.create(path);
    out.write(bytes);
    out.close();
```

Comment: I execute the same code, I see the file created but the content is empty, do you have any idea why ?

Comment: Have you checked the content of your bytes variable? (that chart has content)

Comment: I have used a string.toBytes function so I am sure there is data in it. This is my question related to this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49937723/cannot-write-a-string-to-hdfs-file-using-scala