# Cannot write a string to hdfs file using scala

Tags: scala, file, hdfs

I wrote some code to create a file in hdfs and write bytes to it. This is the code:

```
def write(uri: String, filePath: String, data: String): Unit = {
    System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME", "hibou")
    val path = new Path(filePath + "/hello.txt")
    val conf = new Configuration()
    conf.set("fs.defaultFS", uri)
    val fs = FileSystem.get(conf)
    val os = fs.create(path)
    os.writeBytes(data)
    os.flush()
    fs.close()
  }
```

The code success without error but I only see that file created. When I examine the content of the file with `hdfs -dfs -cat /.../hello.txt` I don't see any content?

Comment: the code is perfectly working. it depends how you are calling write function

Comment: Can you give me more detail ?

Comment: You have to give the details on how you are accessing the write function.